# Ionic: Production build fails for loop running on object in template

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm working with Ionic 5

I created a nested Object in typescript file and running a loop in template to read it.

It works fine with ionic serve but fails when I build it. Here is the code:

```
// declaration
let dataMap:any;

setupData(){
    this.dataMap = {};
    this.dataMap.data = {};

    this.userSubscriptionUsages.forEach((userSubscriptionUsage: any) => {
        mapKey = userSubscriptionUsage.id;

        this.dataMap.created_at = userSubscriptionUsage.created_at;

        if (!this.dataMap.data[mapKey]) {
            this.dataMap.data[mapKey] = {
                serviceCategoryMap: {}
            };
        }

        // Map services to its categories
        userSubscriptionUsage.userSubscriptionUsageDetails.forEach((userSubscriptionUsageDetail: any) => {
            serviceCategoryId = userSubscriptionUsageDetail.service.serviceCategory.id;

            if (!this.dataMap.data[mapKey].serviceCategoryMap[serviceCategoryId]) {
                this.dataMap.data[mapKey].serviceCategoryMap[serviceCategoryId] = {};
                this.dataMap.data[mapKey].serviceCategoryMap[serviceCategoryId].data = [];
                this.dataMap.data[mapKey].serviceCategoryMap[serviceCategoryId].categoryName = userSubscriptionUsageDetail.service.serviceCategory.name;
            }

            // Check if service is already added in service categories list
            if (!this.serviceAlreadyAdded(userSubscriptionUsageDetail.service, this.dataMap.data[mapKey].serviceCategoryMap[serviceCategoryId].data))
                this.dataMap.data[mapKey].serviceCategoryMap[serviceCategoryId].data.push(userSubscriptionUsageDetail.service);
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the template code:

```
    <ion-row *ngFor="let data of dataMap.data | keyvalue">
        <ion-col size="12" class='service-box'>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col size="12">
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col size="12">
                            <span>{{data.value.created_at | date}}</span>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-row>
                <ion-col size="12" *ngFor="let serviceCategory of data.value.serviceCategoryMap | keyvalue">
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col size="12">
                            <strong>{{serviceCategory.value.categoryName}}</strong>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>

                    <ion-row *ngFor="let service of serviceCategory.value.data">
                        <ion-col size="12">{{service.name}}</ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

When I try to build it like this:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

I get the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'serviceCategoryMap' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
<ion-col size="12" *ngFor="let serviceCategory of data.value.serviceCategoryMap | keyvalue">
```

Looks like **data.value** cannot be checked for type although **dataMap** was declared as any.

What am I doing wrong? Should I create a model for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a model for it, or you can try to disable the check for TSLint.

add `suppressExcessPropertyErrors` into the tsconfig.json